having difficulty mocking supabase .eq().eq() with jest
I have this code:
    const result = await req.supabase
      .from("some_table")
      .select()
      .eq("id", id1)
      .eq("landmarks.id", id2)
      .single();

I'm trying to mock it for my test environment but I've been unable to close the gap and get it working -- i'm not sure why.
My current implementation:
  const mockSingle = jest.fn();

  jest.mock("@supabase/supabase-js", () => {
    return {
      createClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return {
          select: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
            eq: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
              eq: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
                single: mockSingle,
              }),
            }),
          }),
        };
      }),
    };
  });

with the following resolved value:

mockSingle.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: { someData: [someData] }, error: null });

I keep getting this error:
Error retrieving records req.supabase.from(...).select(...).eq(...).eq is not a function
edit: i think it's also worth mentioning that if i remove one of the .eq() functions from the chain and remove the equivalent mock jest.fn(), it does line up and work. Something weird seems to happen when it's two .eq().eq().

This is a good example of why you shouldn't mock what you don't own - your test double becomes very complex and your code and tests are too closely coupled to the third party code. If that changes, your tests keep passing even though the code is broken. Write a wrapper/façade layer you own, mock that for low-level tests, and have higher-level tests to ensure it all integrates correctly.

great point, that's very insightful!

This isn't directly addressing your question, but instead of chaining eq(), you can use match() instead.  https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/match

You can use mockReturnThis function to mock chain functions.
So, your mock may look like this:
const mockSingle = jest.fn();

jest.mock("@supabase/supabase-js", () => {
  return {
    createClient: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
      return {
        from: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), // your chain starts from `from()`
        select: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        eq: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
        single: mockSingle,
      };
    }),
  };
});

